# Validação de formulário laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Olá, procurei e não achei bem o que eu procurava para meu projeto Laravel por isso preciso ajuda!
Tenho um formulário simples que recebe o nome, e-mail e uma mensagem do usuário, mas eu gostaria de percorrer o banco de dados e verificar se o e-mail já esta em uso e caso esteja em uso exibir uma mensagem ou alerta.

Então qual logica devo usar? como eu poderia tratar isso? devo usar Validation do próprio Laravel?

Eu sei que poderia atribuir no banco de dados como UNIQUE no campo desejado mas eu não queria ir por este lado.

obs: estou aprendendo Laravel

segue abaixo o codigo do formulario.

```
<form action="/project/public/enviar" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="mensagem" name="mensagem" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Aqui está a View:

```
Route::post('/enviar', 'ContatoController@enviar')->middleware('auth');
```

Aqui está o Controller:

```
public function enviar(Request $request){
    $contato = new Contato();

    $contato->nome = $request->get('nome');
    $contato->email = $request->get('email');
    $contato->mensagem = $request->get('mensagem');
    $contato->save();
```

Como eu disse bem simples mas o à mais que preciso está me deixando de cabelo em pé, desde já agradeço ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho mais fácil utilizar a validação do laravel. Neste caso já existe uma validação pronta:

```
$request->validate(["email" => "unique:contato"]);
```

Então as mensagens de erro serão injetadas na view e podem ser recuperadas assim:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Se você estiver utilizando o laravel  como uma api rest, por exemplo, a forma da validação muda um pouco:

```
//criando validação
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "email" => "unique:contato"
]);
//recuperando mensagem de erro:
$validator->errors()->first()
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator, apenas importe ele assim:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Na função do controller coloque isso:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nomeDoCampo' => 'nomeDaValidação',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        return view('nameOfYourView')
            ->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
```

E para mostrar a mensagem de erro na view:

```
    @if ($errors->any())
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{$error}}
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Link com todos os tipos de validações: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation